# 16V Smart Load Switch

Tags: mosfet, embedded, switching

[image: Load Switch]

I am trying to make a "smart" load switch for my device. I have looked for existing options, but have not found something that can control 16V from a momentary switch but can be turned off by the same switch or a microcontroller. This is my homemade solution. The button on the bottom provides a ground path for the p-type mosfet which powers the circuit and enables the 3.3 voltage rail. The 3.3 voltage rail then provides the ground path once the 3.3V rail comes up. When the microcontroller has booted, it will drive SHUTDOWN high to keep the device on. The microcontroller can sense when the button has been pressed to turn the SHUTDOWN pin off and power off the circuit(this has to be done after the button is released to actually power it off. My question is this, are there any components I am missing that would be necessary for reliable operation? I have made this on a breadboard with a nano and it works, but I'm interested to know what I'm missing.